# ASP.NET CSS - Set Textbox to 100% width of div

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I want to have my ASP.NET C# textbox to span the entire width of the div and be responsive. Also, I am using Bootstrap 4 if there is an option with that.

- I have tried placing a div in a div with centering and expanding.
- margin-left & right set to auto
- display: Block, Flex, and inline-block
- Hard coding size
- CSS Sizing
- Box Sizing
- A dozen or so Bootstrap classes
- plus more.

Here is a picture of what I got.
[image]

Here is the ASPX and HTML Code

```
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <asp:Label ID="lblContactHeader" runat="server" Text="Drop us a line" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="large-label"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name*"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="inputSize"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone*"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" CssClass="inputSize"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email*"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="inputSize"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server" Text="Comments*"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" CssClass="inputSize" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="custContact" runat="server" Type="submit" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-orange btn-right"/>
        </div>
```

Here is the current CSS Code. I have tried over 10 different suggestions on other Stack Overflow posts.

```
.inputSize {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;}
```

Here is the HTML Code Version.

```
                    <label>Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="custName" class="form-control" required />
                    <label>Phone*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="custPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="(###) ###-####" pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" required />
                    <label>Email*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="custEmail" class="form-control" required />
                    <label>Comments*</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="custComm" required ></textarea>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" id="custContact" value="Submit" class="btn btn-orange btn-right"/>
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap you can add the class `form-control` to add the bootstrap input styles which will set `display: block` and fill the space.

Comment: @bhmahler I tried using form-control on the the inputs; however, still not getting the desired results.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are overriding the bootstrap styles? Sounds like this may be the case.

Comment: @bhmahler Thank you for the suggestion!... I had a rogue CSS File that was overwriting my Bootstrap and custom CSS file. It's fixed now! If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to another style sheet overriding the bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) so that you know how those `<div class="row" />` and `<div class="col-*" />` work. Also reading through [reponsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints) would be helpful to understand what those `-sm-`, `-md-`, etc mean.

If you have

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

It will give you 50% width of the screen because Bootstrap uses 12 column system, and 6 is half of it.

If you need 100%, just get rid of `<div class="row" />` and `<div class="col-sm-6" />` or change `<div class="col-sm-6" />` to `<div class="col-sm-12" />`.

To set any input 100% width in regard to its container, just like what @bhmahler said in the comment, you need to set `.form-control` to the input, which will set the input `display: block;` and `width: 100%;`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#layout

Comment: I have two <div class="col-sm-6" /> One is for the left side which is working fine; however, the right side with the general information isn't working properly.

Comment: See my updates. I was not clear what you were asking. Your sample code only had one `col-sm-6` and they're asp.net codes...

Comment: I have added form-control to the CssClass property of each input. Doing this makes it take half the width instead of a third. When I tried to remove the row feature or change this column to col-sm-12 it just pushed the textboxes under the left side; however, didn't expand.

Comment: You would need to paste the generated HTML to your question, rather than that asp.net code. Nobody can re-run that piece of code.

Comment: Hey @David, I add the HTML version of the code at the bottom of the post and I'm still getting the same results with plain HTML. To add, it's with in a form control.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Your HTML version is different than your asp.net version. And in fact, what you posted does take up 100% width: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/uang68t3/2/.